# With Git add command, how to take into account the modifications made on a submodule?

Tags: git

I have a project on my local computer with a *.gitmodules* file.

When I do:

```
git add .
```

I get this message:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> downward
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached downward
```

I made modifications to the "downward" subfolder/modules and **I want to make sure that these modifications are taken into account I do**

```
git submodule add <url> downward
```

This `<url>` argument should be the url of the module, but I got this module from a repo a long time ago and I don't want to use the code of this repo **since I have updated it locally**.

Any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check first if you have a (hidden) `.git` subfolder inside your `download` folder (or one of `download` subfolders).
If so, that would make it a nested Git repository, and would negate its submodule nature.

If you have modified that `download` repository, it is best to:

- fork the original URL in order to have your own repository
- declare the fork URL as your `download` submodule
- add, commit and push to that fork from within your `download` submodule in order to save your own modification.